# Figure out which pages I got permissions for from the Facebook Login popup

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm building a Chatbot and im trying to connect it with the client Facebook Fanpage programmatically, so I can you receive and send messages on the user behalf on the Fanpage.

So far all is good, I got the Facebook login to work, requesting access to the right permissions, and getting the user short and long lived access token.

However, I'm not sure this access token is valid for which Fanpages, The Facebook login lists all the user Fanpages and he can select which he will give the permission to per the screenshot, but nothing is returned in the payload saying which pages he selected, only the access token as below:

```
  "authResponse": {
    "accessToken": "EAAJ911mLyc4BAPsNTMCfVqcf5JkvnGsaZCxXZAZA6slQuubSaZANMB3jsUBZB5ds7opfAuV1ZBB5Vz3NZBLwiN3QO1C5NupvGAbIdzxz91JYWHZCJfwOgawzOswgxAevLDmd6yjRQ4LASROcbnyTtHcnBeE08qvWSYJ6sJrzZCptZB94NZA1tz6tVKOIZCIgrhdaM1IB4feF2LCaF86eIXH1yAZCE",
    "userID": "2917511921114302",
    "expiresIn": 5498,
    "signedRequest": "YpjihSoIBgcl2fUxkVBE2b7_mtXD7RK7ZT7sn77uqRY.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMjkxNzUxODkyMTcxNDMwMiIsImNvZGUiOiJBUUFhNGVZRlJTUnIyNDkwT252dFdEYTlfTnh3cm1QWnNoTUF4bzNUYzdERS00MmZXT0pvTEY4XzUybUJ6VmhzeF81eG05VjFNZV33daVhvM3lQV1FscTE1czZoM25uYUpnTzdObGpxUkJhQTNpRnhtMTA1TFMtbVRPa0dTNGNiNEFpbXN3dTcxcEZiX0hjZG1MVXFldmo5QkVQMXJzYnRkYkw5LWNzSXZlWWIyWmZQR25TNW93aUdCTjRIZmRqdjRSbm9aMkllRDRPN3R1RUtfbmhDMG55cDd1UDZGR1JCOVFaV3ZQQUVEQTNwN2dJX0x3X1ZDYUsteG00Tk9BbkJhZEdnVS16eXJNR3J1S0owZWFLUFF6YkFkNWJRaUJzNmw1a2xvUl9IOFhieFpiMjlaUmJHTjBOUjJoZmk4bHNISU5yMW91SjUyXzJqWTNaTy1xZ3FSX1RObSIsImFsZ29yaXRobSI6IkhNQUMtU0hBMjU2IiwiaXNzdWVkX2F0IjoxNjc1OTUyOTAyfQ",
    "graphDomain": "facebook",
    "data_access_expiration_time": 1683728902
  },
  "status": "connected"
}
```

And screenshots for the page selection from the Facebook login:

[image]
[image]

How can I can get the pages id selected, so I can request later the page access token for those specific pages? Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/ (says there you needed a page access token for that request, but that makes little sense, when you only got the user token at this point. The endpoint works fine with the user token.)

Comment: yea but to get the page access token i need to get a user access token first https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens/

Comment: Yes, _as I said_, this appears to be wrong in the documentation, and using a user token works fine.